# Create an instance of a class from SQL query

Tags: python, sqlite, instantiation

I have the following class:

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self, name, date):
        self.name = name
        self.date = date
```

Now I have a function in another module, which connects to a SQLite database and executes a query:

```
def getEntry(user):
    data = []
    connection = lite.connect(database)                                                                 
    with connection:                                                                 
        cur = connection.cursor()                                                    
        cur.execute("SELECT name, date FROM table WHERE column = ?", [user])
        events = cur.fetchall()                                                      
        # instantiate an instance of `SomeClass`
        return data
```

So how would I create an instance of `SomeClass` and pass `name` and `date` entries to my newly created instance?

Comment: Have you considered using a library to do this for you? Django is primarily a web framework, but its database support and ORM are phenomenal.

Comment: I'm already using cherryPy, don't really want to use Django on top of that. Can't be that hard to accomplish the above, or is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `fetchall()` returns a list of the rows, you should be able to do this (this should cover occasions where multiple results are returned as well):

```py
for result in events:
    my_instance = SomeClass(result[0], result[1])
    # Do whatever you want to do with the instances, which looks like
    # it may be appending to data
    data.append(my_instance) # Or data.append(SomeClass(result[0], result[1]))
```

Can't test it right now, so apologies if it is way off :)

Comment: Or `return  [SomeClass(*row) for row in cur]`

Comment: @StevenRumbalski Even better :)